# How to hide unloaded picture (<img> tag)?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I use Leaflet.js library to display my custom map. When I press Ctrl+F5 Im getting several  blocks without loaded picture. Is it possible to use any css pseudo-element or js event handler to make just created images invisible?

Additional info. Lowest coordinates from top-left are [0,0], but as you can see Leaflet.js loads [-1,0].
[image]

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#gridlayer-bounds

Answer (score 0):

how about a render condition. each img tag should have a `display: none` any only thoose who have img src which is not empty get the `display: inline`

Comment: I use [this url to load lib](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js). Of'course I can download it to modify, but I dont have enouth skill to do that. At least I'm going to do that, if I will not find another way.